# Creating a drop down box for price range using SQL commands

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

I am having trouble filtering my table, I have filtered it for product category but I am unsure how to do it when looking at numbers.

**Expected Outcome**

What I expect to see when the user presses the submit button is for the table to change to what ever it was that submitted. For example, in the drop down box there is an option for '0 - 1', this meaning at price range less than a pound. If I was to press this I would expect to see the table change, showing only products with a price less than 1 pound.

**What the actual outcome is**

At the moment I am getting different errors every time I try something new, I first attempted to copy the category option but that didn't work.

**Could I do something like this?**

*For the drop down box*

```
<form action="database.php" method="post">
<select name="price" id="price">
    <option value="?">All Products</option>
    <option value="?">Less than £1</option>
    <option value="?">More than £1, Less than £5</option>
    <option value="?">More than £5, Less than £10</option>
</select>
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Would not know what to put for the value.

*The SQL code*

```
$'?' = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
    Description, Price FROM food WHERE Price = BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00");

$'?' = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
    Description, Price FROM food WHERE Price = BETWEEN 1.00 AND 5.00");

$'?' = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
    Description, Price FROM food WHERE Price = BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00");
```

*Here is my current code for implement the table*

```
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=hostname.com port=1234
                                        dbname=******* user=guest password=********");
    // Empty var that will be populated if the form is submitted
    $where = '';
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
        // Where conditional that will be used in the SQL query
        $where = " WHERE Category = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['category'])."'";
            }
        }
        $res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price 
        FROM food " . $where . " ORDER BY Category ASC");
            echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
            while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
        echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST' action='addToBasket.php'>
        <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
        </form></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    echo "</table>\n";
```

I will need another Where conditional

```
$where = " WHERE Price= '".pg_escape_string($_POST['price'])."'";
```

Is there a better way to do a filter for price range?

Comment: make it simpler, use to select(dropdown) with one being "From...." and the other being "To.....", and simply pass it on to the query? or having the option value as BETWEEN from? and to?....

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean sorry

Comment: Ahh okay, yeah that does seem a more obvious way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First php isnt my strength so take it just as guidelines.

Just put some id number for each option

```
<select name="price" id="price">
    <option value="1">All Products</option>
    <option value="2">Less than £1</option>
    <option value="3">More than £1, Less than £5</option>
    <option value="4">More than £5, Less than £10</option>
```

Then you have the `where`

```
$where = " WHERE Category = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['category'])."'";

switch ($_POST['price']) {
     case 2: 
           $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00";
           break;
     case 3: 
           $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 5.00";
           break;
     case 4: 
           $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00";
           break;
     default:
           break;
}

$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price 
    FROM food " . $where . " ORDER BY Category ASC");
```

**NOTE:**

`BETWEEN` works like `0.00 <= price AND price <= 1.00` so if one item price is exactly `1.00` will also appear on both the first and second range.

**NOTE 2:**

A better option is create a table `PriceRange` in database this way you can update or add new ranges very easy without have to change the php page.

```
RangeID    LowerPrice   UpperPrice
  1            0         1.000.000.000
  2            0              1
  3            1              5 
  4            5             10
```

Your query will be something like

```
SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price 
FROM food f
JOIN PriceRange p
  ON f.Price BETWEEN p.LowerPrice AND p.UpperPrice
WHERE Category = $_POST['category']
  AND RangeID = $_POST['price']
```

Comment: I have implemented that into my code, but when I select one of the options from the drop down box, nothing happens, the pages reloads but once it has, the table is exactly the same.

Comment: Create a variable `$strQuery` and build your query there and execute `$res = pg_query($strQuery)` do that and show me your `$strQuery` value. You can also try that into the db direct to see what result you get.

Comment: I found one error, check the update. Put a wrong `=` on `Price = BETWEEN`

Comment: I'm not trying to be awkward but I'm now thinking of doing this a different way, instead of having a drop down box, I will have two inputs for user to define their own values. I think that would be more sensible

Comment: Its ok, but that is a different question. You can always create a new one.

Comment: Yes i will, thanks for your help Juan! As this works, i will put it as answered!

Comment: btw depending on you UI, you may want offer both options. the fixed ranges will be faster for user, and the custom ranges for user need the detailed result